# Testcontainers: turn on/off multiple containers in abstract class. (Combination of containers in tests)

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, testcontainers

I would like to ask if there is a way, how to design an abstract class with testcontainers for integration tests with a combination of multiple testcontainers.
I would like to have one class with definitions of all containers needed for the application and turn them on/off based on the needs of the integration test.
Example:
Application needs:

- database
- smtp
- rabbitMQ
- ....

Is there a way for setting up an abstract class for all these containers and turn on only the needed combination for the current integration test? All tests don't need to run SMTP or the same needs database and rabbit,....
Set up abstract class ancestor for container setup is suggested by Testcontainers but there is no way how to manage which containers will be started from descendants.

Since it is called from static method I can't find a way how to manage it:

```
@BeforeAll
public static void startContainers() {
    if (runKeycloak()) {
        keycloak.start();
    }
    if (runPostgres()) {
        postgreSQLContainer.start();
    }
}
```

Did I miss something basic?

Because it is static it can't be managed with spring properties, I can't override class attribute or anything similar.

Comment: Are you in JUnit 5? If so, implementing with [extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) is much easier than it sounds!

Comment: Exactly! Thanks @NikosParaskevopoulos. This is what I was looking for. Unfortunately I can't use it because I need to set up Spring properties based on started container. So I need to wait: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29729

Comment: Yes, I see the problem, what a pity... I hope it will get resolved soon. What I would do is to see the code of Spring that handles the `@DynamicPropertySource`. Maybe you can find ways to override the configuration manually from within the JUnit extension.